# Why can't I directly access a property of an object literal?

Tags: javascript

Why the following syntax

```
{a:1,b:2}.constructor
```

is invalid, whereas

```
[1,2].constructor
```

is valid?

Comment: `({a:1,b:2}).constructor`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`{a:1,b:2}.constructor` is not invalid syntax, but it is ambiguous, because `{}` denotes a block, or an object? So you have to disambiguate the expression with parentheses, like `({a:1,b:2}).constructor`. Now JavaScript knows you meant to use an object.

If you use that syntax in a context where it is clearly an object, then there is no ambiguity:

```
console.log({a:1,b:2}.constructor) // works fine
```

Answer (score 13):

Curve brackets at the start of a line is recognized as a [*code block*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) instead of an [*object literal*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

If you look at the error in the console, you can see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`. So, the error is not in calling the *constructor* property.

Also, when you write in the console

```
{a:1}
```

JS interprets this as a block with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and not an object with property `a`.

Comment: What's a `line`? Semicolon-dependent languages (especially JS with its funny rules) don't know about `line`s. But `;{1:2}.constructor` is invalid. Perhaps you meant `statement` or `expression` over `line`?