# What is the mechanics of \J in Replace

Tags: emeditor

I am now confused by `\J` in Replace Dialog Box. I want to know how does emeditor treat the js code after `\J`.

First, to my understanding, emeditor does a text substitute first. For example, to check if there are some referring groups like `\0`, `\1`...If so, substitue them with corresponding strings.
Then, I think emeditor treats the code as an expression and calls js interpreter to evaluate it, gets the evaluation value which will be the replacement string.

So, the js code after `\J` must be a valid js expression. In other words, if `console.log(SOMECODE)` works without error in my firefox console, then SOMECODE basically works in `\J SOMECODE`. And I've been follwing this rule and written some code to tweak matched string. Up to now, it is all fine.

Right now, I'm using a simple js expression with \J: `\J {A:"B", C:"D"}.\0`.But this isn't working. My `\0` matches "A" and I'm sure that `{A:"B", C:"D"}.A` is a valid expression. Emeditor alerts me with "Missing ;". I don't understand why semicolon is needed here.

I have checked manual regarding this part, and found some demo code:

```
\J "\0" + "abc"
\J "\0".substr( 0, 5 );
\J \0 * 100;
\J parseFloat( \0 ).toFixed(2);
\J cell( -1 )
\J parseFloat( cell( -1 ) ) + parseFloat( cell( -2 ) )
```

Well, some are valid js expression. Others end with semicolon.
So this proves my understanding wrong which is why I'm confused now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this expression `{A:"B", C:"D"}.A` is supported only in newer versions of JavaScript. Many new expressions in modern **JavaScript/ECMAScript** are not available in EmEditor. The **Replace Expressions** use **Chakra** (equivalent to **Microsoft Edge Legacy**), and support up to **ECMAScript 5.1**, thus newer methods introduced after **ECMAScript 5.1** are not supported.

**Updated**

Please use: `\J ({A:"B", C:"D"}).A`

**Reference**: [Why can't I directly access a property of an object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944491/why-cant-i-directly-access-a-property-of-an-object-literal)

Comment: I believe syntax like `{A:"B", C:"D"}.A` is supported in ealier versions of JavaScript, if not the first version of JavaScript. And In my problem, I changed my code to `\J var a = {A:"B", C:"D"}.A; a`. This worked. I'm more confused now. I don't know how this is a valid expression but `{A:"B", C:"D"}.A` isn't.

Comment: I've reproduced the issue. `\J var a = {A:"B", C:"D"}.A; a` works but `\J {A:"B", C:"D"}.A` doesn't. I debuged the code, but this might be a bug in Chakra. Can you work around using similar to `\J var a = {A:"B", C:"D"}.A; a`?

Comment: I think I've found the reason. I changed my code to `\J ({A:"B", C:"D"}).A`. It worked fine. If you're interested, you can check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35944491/why-cant-i-directly-access-a-property-of-an-object-literal]

Comment: Great! I'm glad to know it wasn't a bug. Thank you for letting me know.